# What is wrong with my while-loop?

Tags: ruby

I am re-doing the 18 Euler challenges I finished so far in Ruby and I love it. Unfortunately I make some beginner mistakes and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Specifically, what is wrong with the code below? I try to add all fibonacci numbers under 4 million.

```
start = Time.now

def sum_fibonacci_till_4_million
    previous_previous_value = 1
    previous_value = 2
    i = 2
    fibo = Array.new

    while previous_value < 4000000 do
        fibo.push(previous_previous_value)
        fibo.push(previous_value)

        temp = previous_value
        previous_value = previous_value + previous_previous_value
        previous_previous_value = temp

        i++
    end

    return fibo.inject(:+)
end

puts "The answer is #{sum_fibonacci_till_4_million()} and it took #{(start - Time.now) 
* 1000} milliseconds."
```

The output I get is

```
2.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
2.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
...ime.now) * 1000} milliseconds."
...
```

I have had this error before and I managed to fix it with a for-loop. But obviously something is wrong with my end-statement. I do not know what.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: When you have a general syntax error like this, you can use a divide-and-conquer approach to find it. First you might comment out the `while/end` loop.  No more syntax error!  Next comment out just the lines inside the `while/end` loop.  No error.  Eventually you'll find there is no syntax error when just `i++` is commented out.  As `i.class => Fixnum`, check the `Fixnum` docs . No `:++` method! Could it be in one of the classes in `Fixnum.ancestors`? `Fixnum.instance_methods.include?(:++) => false` says 'no'. But why no `:++` method?  Google "Ruby i++". PS You should show `require 'time'`.

Answer (score 7):

`i++` is not allowed in ruby. Write `i += 1`.

> [Ruby has no pre/post increment/decrement operator](http://docs.ruby-doc.com/docs/Newcomers/ruby.html#operators). For instance, x++ or x-- will fail to parse. More importantly, ++x or --x will do nothing! In fact, they behave as multiple unary prefix operators: -x == ---x == -----x == ...... To increment a number, simply write x += 1.

[`[ruby-talk:18951] Re: notes from a Ruby newbie - blade`](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/18951)

> | There are no post- or pre-increment or decrement operators!
>
> **No.  Because I couldn't give them object-oriented semantics.  They would be essentially assignments.**

Comment: Ah interesting. Why not?

Comment: @user2609980 Because it doesn't.

Comment: @user2609980 -1 on the question. If you were just asking why Ruby does not have `++` and `--`, then that can be meaningful, but using something that does not exist is simple carelessness. It is not written anywhere in the document that such thing exists. Why would you think Ruby has it? You are sloppy. It is like randomly mixing some Greek word into an English sentence, and asking "Why was this sentence not understood?"

Comment: @sawa Wow, that's harsh. With this attitude, you could dismiss most questions on SO with "RTFM!"

Comment: @awendt I agree that my attitude is along RTFM. In such typical cases, the OP is lazy, which I hate as well. But in this case, it goes even beyond that. The OP is asking about something that does not exist in the manual: something that the OP had made up in their mind in the context of Ruby.